# Dryer not producing heat

Tags: dryer, gas, heat

I have an older style whirlpool gas dryer. It’s not producing any heat. I hear it click every 2-3 minutes like a switch is being flicked, almost sounds like when you press a pilot light switch. It’s coming for the bottom of the dryer.

Make of dryer - whirlpool Model number of dryer - CGM2751KQ3 Serial number - MS0901511 Type - BDOT-NAT-CS22

Comment: do you have gas ? is it burning ?

Comment: Yes I have gas , I don’t think it’s not burning

Comment: so you do not see the flame

Comment: read this https://www.partselect.com/Models/CGM2751KQ3/Symptoms/No-heat-or-not-enough-heat/

Comment: Did you fix the gas leaking smell from before?